# How to extract standard error from ARIMA output in R?

Tags: r, arima, standard-error

After I run the `arima` function in R, I get an output that gives me the coefficients and the standard errors of the coefficients.  Pulling the coefficients is easy, you just do `arima$coef`.

How do I pull out the standard errors in the output of `arima`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The help file suggests `coef( )` to access the coefficients and `vcov( )` to access the variance matrix. The standard errors of the coefficients would then be `sqrt(diag(vcov( ))`.

> `coef`: a vector of AR, MA and regression coefficients, which can be
>   extracted by the `coef` method.
>
> `var.coef`: the estimated variance matrix
>   of the coefficients `coef`, which can be extracted by the `vcov` method.

Note that questions like this, which are solely about coding and not at all about statistics, are a better fit on stackoverflow.com than here on CrossValidated.  You're also more likely to get good help if you demonstrate that you've read the help files before posting.

Comment: ok i didn't know i had to sqrt diag the varcoef term

Comment: Wouldn't `sqrt(diag(vcov())` give you the standard deviation, not the standard error? If you want the standard error of the mean, you would still need to divide by the square root of the sample size.

Comment: @Elyce There are several problems with that, because the data in an ARIMA model are explicitly not independent.  As Aaron explains in this answer, `var.coef` estimates the variance matrix of the (estimated) coefficients: by definition, its diagonal elements are the *sampling variances* of the coefficient estimates; that is, they are the squares of the standard errors.